# How to fix flutter packages get failed depends on pubgapi >=0.0.2 which requires SDK version >=1.20.1 <=2.0.0

Tags: flutter

I have created a flutter project where i am using the API of PUBG game after adding dependencies it is showing an error

```
  dependencies:
    flutter:
     sdk: flutter
    cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
    pubgapi: ^0.1.1
```

[pubspec.yaml Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RPjd.png)

I have tried this but nothing happens i am getting the same error

```
   flutter channel dev
   flutter upgrade
```

Comment: That package hasn't been updated for 2 years. https://pub.dev/packages/pubgapi#-analysis-tab- it hasn't been updated to Dart 2. Clone the package from GitHub and update it to Dart 2 and run the unit tests. Then depend on your local copy. Contact the author to see if they would like your updated version.

Comment: Can your tell me how to update that package

Comment: https://dart.dev/dart-2#general-process